# What are the formulas for the MAE , MSE when output is a vector?

Tags: machine-learning, linear-algebra

What are the formulas for the MAE , MSE  when output is a vector?

MAE: Mean Absolute Error

MSE: Mean squared error

Comment: By output, do you mean the output of your model? And I'm assuming the label would be a similarly shaped vector as well?

Comment: yes, i mean the output of the model (and yes label is a vector also).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd just sum the losses over each of the dimensions.

If your model outputs a vector of size $d$, it's functionally the same as if you had a model that outputs $d$ different outputs, with $d$ different labels.

If you had $d$ labels, for some loss $L$:
$$\sum_{i\ \in\ [1 .. d]} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j\ \in\ [1..n]} \mathcal{L}(Y_{j,i}, \hat{Y}_{j,i}) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j\ \in\ [1..n]} \sum_{i\ \in\ [1 .. d]} \mathcal{L}(Y_{j,i}, \hat{Y}_{j,i})$$

[You can see this, for example, for image generation tasks, where both the target and the prediction are matrices.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.08861) For each image prediction, they average the loss over each of the pixels.